# Java - Array element not keeping data set

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that when called checks through an array using a for loop for an element of 0. If it finds one, it replaces it with a one (for now). For some reason, it seems the element resets to 0 after the method is called.

```
public int inv[] = new int[5];
boolean confirmation;

public void requestPickUp() {
    confirmation = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (inv[i] == 0 && !confirmation) {
            confirmation = true;
            inv[i] = 1;
        }
    }
}

public void display() {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++) {
        System.out.println(inv[i2]);
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Calling the method with
    `inv.requestPickUp();`

Comment: Could you share your calls for these methods?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (I'd advise you to use private fields, and also to add more whitespace within your lines of code, but those won't affect your question.)

Comment: You're probably constructing two different instances (objects) of your class. Each of these has it's own `inv` variable. You need to call both methods on the same instance.

Comment: Erwin Bolwidt was correct. Made the Inventory object static and it worked.

Comment: Your code seems fine for the purpose you have mentioned (replacing value 0 with 1). Please share your array initialization code and the code that calls these methods. Please post the full code. These extracts are not much of help to analyze the problem.

Comment: public field variables are not recommended. any other class can directly modify the values other than requestPickup().  Your requestPickUp() is ok. Please post the code which invoke the requestPickup() method.